# How to override Spring data rest repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have module with some spring data repository. In another module I want to create rest repositories. If I just add spring-data-rest module then I will get wrong urls (I want to change names), so I tried to extends these interfaces, but it seems that created subinterfaces just ignored, does anybody know how to solved this problem?

This is base repository:

```
@Repository
public interface SectorRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SectorTrest, Long> {}
```

It is its subclass:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "sectors", path = "sectors", itemResourceRel = "sector")
public interface SectorRepository extends package.SectorRepository {}
```

Comment: Please add some code so that we can give proper solution.

Comment: I added code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing "sectors" is the path automatically used by your original repository, try to change "sectors" with something else and see if your rest repository is exposed.